# Magento 2.2 store view switching add ___store=default to url

Tags: magento2, store-switcher

Preconditions:

- Magento 2.2
- With 2 store views ( default and en )

Steps to reproduce:

- Load home page: url = myeshop.com/
- Switch store view: url = myeshop.com/?___store=en
- Switch again store view: url = myeshop.com/?___store=en?___store=default

Result:

- There has been an error processing your request

When I set "Add Store Code to URL" to 'Yes' in Stores > Configuration > General > Web it works properly. But it is not accepted.

Previously, at 2.1.9 the url remained the same after any store view switch.

Any advice?

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10908) fixed in [Magento v2.2.2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.2CE.html#fixes-and-enhancements).

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same problem with a pice of Javascript code:

```
define([
        "jquery"
    ],
    function ($) {
        "use strict";

        $('a[data-post*="?___store=en?___store=tr"]').each(function(){
            var $link = $(this);
            var post = $link.attr('data-post');
            $link.attr('data-post', post.replace('?___store=en?___store=tr', '?___store=tr'));
        });

        $('a[data-post*="?___store=tr?___store=en"]').each(function(){
            var $link = $(this);
            var post = $link.attr('data-post');
            $link.attr('data-post', post.replace('?___store=tr?___store=en', '?___store=en'));
        });

    }
);
```

But I know that this is not the right approach.

Any other advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported and discussed here :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10908

And the bug has been fixed here :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11337

I guess it will be automatically fixed with the next release of Magento 2.2.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem remains in 2.2.0. Now we are waiting for 2.2.1.

Comment: The problem remains in 2.2.1